# Is there an equivalent to Lookups but executing in target host instead of local?

Tags: ansible, properties-file

In Ansible, when I need to read properties from a Java properties file (`.properties`), I do something like:

```
- name: Read properties
  set_fact:
    myProp1: {{ lookup('ini', 'myProp1 type=properties file=/path/to/file.properties }} 
    myProp2: {{ lookup('ini', 'myProp2 type=properties file=/path/to/file.properties }}
```

But, as [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html) says:

> Lookups occur on the local computer, not on the remote computer.

How can I do it if the properties file is located in remote target host? **I can't use include_vars, since my properties file has Java properties file format.**

Comment: If the properties are critical to ansible tasks shouldn't they be on your control host, and pushed to the target/remote rather than the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, `lookup` is local. One possible solution is I used which may not work in all situations is to fetch it locally and then call lookup. Make sure you read about [fetch module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html) before attempting this:

```
- fetch: 
    src: /path/to/file.properties
    dest: /tmp/file.properties
    flat: yes

- name: Read properties
  set_fact:
    myProp1: {{ lookup('ini', 'myProp1 type=properties file=/tmp/file.properties }} 
    myProp2: {{ lookup('ini', 'myProp2 type=properties file=/tmp/file.properties }}
```

**CAUTION**: This is just a workaround, not a solution.